# Implementing an interface which inherits from two interfaces with the same method

Tags: c#, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have project with lots of interfaces with overlapping calculation methods:

```
    public interface Interface1
    {
        public double CalcStuff( int x );
    }

    public interface Interface2
    {
        public double CalcStuff( int x );
    }

    public interface InterfaceJoined : Interface1, Interface2
    {
    }

    public class ClassJoined : InterfaceJoined
     {
        public double CalcStuff( int x ) { return x*x; }
    }
```

I want the implementing class to be assignable as all three interfaces `Interface1, Interface2, InterfaceJoined`.

```
        Interface1 calculator1 = new ClassJoined( );

        Interface2 calculator2 = new ClassJoined( );

        InterfaceJoined calculatorJoined = new ClassJoined( );

        double result1 = calculator1.CalcStuff( 20 ); // works

        double result2 = calculator2.CalcStuff( 20 ); // works

        double resultJoined = calculatorJoined.CalcStuff( 20 ); // "the call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties"
```

I want the interfaces to have the same implementation. No need to distinguish here. How can I achieve that? Is this whole idea bad design?

Thx and greetings.

Comment: You can explicitly tell which implementation is for which interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Comment: I can't find the situation with public interface InterfaceJoined : Interface1, Interface2 in your link.

Comment: What you want to do, as you put it, is not going to work. The error message is pretty clear. If you were the compiler, which one would you execute? You can either pick one version randomly, or as it happens, throw an exception because the call is ambiguous. You assume it would have the exact same implementation, but you can do something different in each method (explicit implementation), even if it makes no sense, nothing stops you, so the compiler cannot make assumptions here.

Comment: Maybe the other way round: you could extract the common methods to separate base interfaces and derive your existing interfaces from these, i.e. `interface ICalcStuff { double CalcStuff(int x); }` and then `interface Interface1 : ICalcStuff { }` `interface Interface2 : ICalcStuff { }` and `class ClassJoined : Interface1, Interface2 { }`

Comment: Yes, this would be possible, but would end up in a big interface inheritance tree, because I have the situation very often.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i was able to come up is combining explicit default method implementation for interface with hiding the `Interface1.CalcStuff` and `Interface2.CalcStuff` methods via `new` keyword:

```
public interface InterfaceJoined : Interface1, Interface2
{
    double Interface1.CalcStuff(int x) => CalcStuff(x);
    double Interface2.CalcStuff(int x) => CalcStuff(x);
    new double CalcStuff(int x);
}
```